# Can Google Analytics help me discover where my users are coming from?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website using google analytics, how do I know which Website a user redirects to my Website?
Is there anyone who made it before?
Thank you.... <3

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related rather related to the google analytics web application may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so logging into GA, under Acquisition > All Traffic > Referrals on the left.